# What changes are made to ./.dns?

Tags: shell, find, dns

My server hosted at Hostgator was recently hit by malware and hence to monitor the file system I use `find -mmin -xx` command at regular intervals. But everytime I run the find command, I see the first 2 results returned are the same:

```
ramnath@mysite.com [~]# find -mmin -10
./.bash_history
./.dns
```

While the `./.bash_history` is understable, I can't really figure out what changes are made to the `./.dns` entry? Although it should be noted that on physical verification of the dns entry I find no altercations.

Pls help me understand.

Answer (score 0):

.dns is not exactly something that should be modified with everything you do. I can see two possibilities:

- Your hoster installed something to help them debug if things go wrong.
- The malware isn't completely removed yet.

In both cases, I would recommend talking to your hoster.

Comment: Although I have been spending 2-3 hours to keep the server clean, I fear that there are still some malware/automated scripts still residing. Now only I can see a host of email being sent by some website. Not sure if these unsolicited emails has anything to do with the dns entry.

Comment: If it's sending mails you didn't ask for, combined with the changing file, it's extremely likely to still be compromised. Switch it off *now*, and talk to your hoster. Note that once your machine is compromised, whoever did it is quite likely to use a number of tricks to have something hidden on your machine so that if you try to clean it, they'll get it back almost immediately. The safe course of action is not to try to clean it, but to reinstall it and restore from backups. You do have backups, right?

Comment: Yes I do have backups and I have spoken to my hoster to draw their attention. I can't switch it off as a number of client sites are also hosted. All said, which the infrequent change to the dns entry (physically cant figure out the change though).